# Best way to convert "foo" into "\x66\x6f\x6f"

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex

I'm looking for a way to convert strings into their escaped hexadecimal representations in Python so that e.g. `"foo"` becomes `"\x66\x6f\x6f"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `hex` builtin and a generator expression:

```
>>> print ''.join('\\'+hex(ord(char))[1:] for char in 'foo')
\x66\x6f\x6f
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's not an answer, just comparisons of previous solutions.

```
In [76]: # short string
In [77]: s = 'foo'

In [78]: # Alexander's solution
In [79]: timeit "".join(map(hex,map(ord, list(s)))).replace("0x","\\x")
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.89 µs per loop

In [80]: # Rawing's solution
In [81]: timeit ''.join(['\\'+hex(ord(char))[1:] for char in s])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 µs per loop

In [82]: # Bhargav Rao's solution
In [83]: timeit ''.join('\\'+hex(ord(char))[1:] for char in s)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop

In [84]: # huge string
In [85]: s = 'f' * 100000

In [86]: # Alexander's solution
In [87]: timeit "".join(map(hex,map(ord, list(s)))).replace("0x","\\x")
100 loops, best of 3: 15.7 ms per loop

In [88]: # Rawing's solution
In [89]: timeit ''.join(['\\'+hex(ord(char))[1:] for char in s])
10 loops, best of 3: 25 ms per loop

In [90]: # Bhargav Rao's solution
In [91]: timeit ''.join('\\'+hex(ord(char))[1:] for char in s)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.8 ms per loop

In [92]:

In [115] # Padraic Cunningham's solution
In [116]: s = 'foo'

In [117]: timeit ("\\x{:x}" * len(s)).format(*map(ord,s))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.57 µs per loop

In [118]: s = 'f' * 100000

In [119]: timeit ("\\x{:x}" * len(s)).format(*map(ord,s))
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop

In [120]:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"".join(map(hex,map(ord, "foo"))).replace("0x","\\x")
```

Comment: calling list on the string is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `encode` and specifying `"hex"` (Python 2.7):

```
"".join(r"\x" + char.encode("hex") for char in "foo")
```

Which prints:

```
\x66\x6f\x6f
```

The encoding approach seems to be much trickier in Python 3 - you might be better off using other methods!

```
>>> import binascii
>>> "".join(r"\x" + h for h in (binascii.hexlify(c.encode()).decode() for c in "foo"))
\x66\x6f\x6f
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use builtins

```
>>> s = 'foo'
>>> print "".join([hex(ord(i)) for i in s]).replace('0x','\\x')
\x66\x6f\x6f
```

[ord](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord)

> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string

[hex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex)

> Convert an integer number (of any size) to a lowercase hexadecimal string prefixed with “0x”

Comment: Do you see the difference between `0x66` and `\x66`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use str.format:

```
print("".join(["\\x{:x}".format(ord(c)) for c in s]))
```

Or using map which I imagine will be the most efficient:

```
print(("\\x{:x}" * len(s)).format(*map(ord,s)))

\x66\x6f\x6f
\x66\x6f\x6f
```